# What template language does Tumblr use?

Tags: templates, themes, template-engine, tumblr

[Tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/custom_themes) uses a very simple template language for it's themes:

```
{block:Text}
    <li class="post text">
        {block:Title}
            <h3><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h3>
        {/block:Title}

        {Body}
    </li>
{/block:Text}
```

[Start.io](http://start.io/help/layouts) also uses the same format:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{Name} @ start.io</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {Groups}
      <h1>{Name}</h1>
      <ul>
      {Links}
        <li><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></li>
      {/Links}
      </ul>
    {/Groups}
  </body>
</html>
```

Is it custom made, or does it use an existing template language?

If it's custom made, can you suggest some references for creating something similar?

Answer (score 3):

These template engines appear custom-made, though they look extremely similar to [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/crashcourse.php).

Comment: I think Tumbler’s template language is quite different from Smarty because it uses blocks instead of if/else statements and it has almost no programming logic (unlike Smarty). I think the template language looks more like a simplified version of the template language of [ExpressionEngine](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/overview/tags.html) and [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html), which is also custom-made and quite limited.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... I think it's custom made, since it isn't mentioned [in the tumblr docs](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/custom_themes), which I suppose it would if they would use a existing template language.

[JSON Template](http://json-template.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/Introducing-JSON-Template.html) seems to be a fairly similar template language, though. Try it :)

Answer (score 1):

I recently published a PHP template engine that does exactly that.
Get it from: https://www.ohloh.net/p/pheme

Comment: I think this beats the idea of a client-side templating language. I don't think Tumblr wants to run user-generated code on their servers.

Answer (score 1):

Tumblr certainly has a custom parser. Check out [my answer on Quora](http://www.quora.com/What-templating-engine-template-language-does-Tumblr-use-to-power-its-layouts/answer/Chris-Lloyd) for a couple of example as to why this is.

Whilst JSONTemplate and Smarty use the same curly brace syntax for variables, they aren't compatible. In addition, one can tell that Start.io uses a different parser as it allows for [custom conditionals](http://start.io/help/layouts#conditionals). The Start.io conditional format is `{if:Var}` or `{if:Var < Num}`. In Tumblr this would be written as a single element block if the variable is official (`{block:Var}`) else if the variable is specified by the user in a `<meta>` tag it would use the `{block:IfUserVar}` syntax.